# Best approach for this type of header/menu?

Tags: css, menu, menuitem

I'd like to make in html/css this header (see picture) that I created using fireworks. This issue is that I'm not sure what the best approach is for this multi level menu. Was thinking of several DIVs next to each other (one per menu category Topic I, Topic II, etc)) and within each DIV text/hyperlink for each sub-menu items (Biography, Publications, etc) but that does not sound as a the "cleanest" approach. Any suggestions? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You'll need to at least post the HTML.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? If it's HTML5, you could use `<nav><ul><li>...</li><ul><nav>`. Should the header be position fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've written you up an ultra-quick jsfiddle, which might server as a decent starting point. I basically just used nested divs inside a `<header>` tag, simply to aid code readability.

[http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/L9h7c/](http://jsfiddle.net/bernie1227/L9h7c/1/)

Comment: Thanks Bernie. But my issue is mainly with the sub-menu items (ie. Biography & publications under Topic I, etc.), any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @Greg, sure, do you want them dropdown? Or just nested ul's?

Comment: @ Bernie, always visible so I guess nested - tks a lot

Comment: @Greg, fiddle updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernie! Just one last question: Am I correct that in your fiddle, Menu items (Topic I, Topic II, etc) are treated separately than sub-menu items (Biography, Publications, etc.) which would explain why sub-menu items are not perfectly aligned under the Topic they belong to?

Comment: @greg, Yep, that's correct. What I've done, is put two div's, one containing the menu items and one with the submenu items. I the used some relative positioning on each in order to space them out. (The issue with the alignment could probably be solved by some measurement tweaking)